# get content of page , append into a script tag

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the html within the document.write from a page , and load,append to a new div on another page. Here is the full page source code. I'd just like to get the table and append to a #newDIV

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" title="Wrap Long Lines">
</head>

<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
  <pre>document.write('<table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="report" id="livescoring"><caption><span>Live Scoring</span></caption><tbody><tr><th>Week 19</th></tr><tr class="oddtablerow"><td><a target="_blank" href="http://www03.myfantasyleague.com/2016/live_scoring_summary?L=75656&amp;W=19">Live Scoring Summary</a>\
</td></tr><tr class="eventablerow"><td><a target="_blank" href="http://www03.myfantasyleague.com/2016/live_scoring?L=75656&amp;W=19">Live Scoring Details</a>\
</td></tr></tbody></table>');
  </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

i want to get the doc write table created within the "pre" tag

I tried to simply load the content into a new div using .load , but that didn't work

So it would render on a new page like this

```
<div id="newDIV"><table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="report" id="livescoring"><caption><span>Live Scoring</span></caption><tbody><tr><th>Week 19</th></tr><tr class="oddtablerow"><td><a target="_blank" href="http://www03.myfantasyleague.com/2016/live_scoring_summary?L=75656&amp;W=19">Live Scoring Summary</a>
```

Live Scoring Details

Comment: Can you rewrite your question clearer. It's not very clear what you're after

Comment: thanks Michael, i have done so , hope its more clear

Comment: Let me see if I got this straight. You want to navigate to another page, transport a DOM element with you and append it to an element in that page, after the page loads. Is this it? That's by far the wildest idea I've heard all day, and it's been a full day here, lol. It can't be done per-se, but there are workarounds.

Comment: This website , allows you to embed some precreated modules , but only use them offsite , i'm wanting to get this document.write embed table and write it back to another page on the same site , as they permit users a lot of control to load javascript,css,html for their own page layouts

Comment: In that case, your best bet, by far, is to use browser storage. Turn element into string by encoding it, store, go on the other page, load, decode, append to DOM. Done. Question is, does it have events? If so, can you load the scripts that add them in the new page? Most scripts run on `window.load`. If you append your element on `document.ready`, you should be covered.

Comment: no scripts are required for the tables created , can you give an example on how to accomplish your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Is the domain for both pages the same? Because if you will use LocalStorage you need both pages to be of the same domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MichaelSeltenreich noted, this will only work if you're on the same domain. In the first page, you'd need to store the string with something like

```
let text = document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML
  .replace("document.write('","")
  .replace("');","");
localStorage.setItem('myTable', text);
```

...probably followed by changing the page:

```
window.location.replace("/your-desired-path");
```

...and, on the other page

```
let text = localStorage.getItem('myTable');
// go wild...
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please note I changed `.href  =`  with `.replace()`. The difference is it doesn't create a point in your browser history now. It's like you navigated directly to the second page. Have it your way, how it's more convenient. Have fun!